# SQL get available between to dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have two tables. These look like this

> Table cars

```
+====+=========+=============+
| ID | mark    | description |
+====+=========+=============+
| 1  | 1234 AB | Volvo V70   |
+----+---------+-------------+
| 2  | 4567 CD | VW GOLF     |
+====+=========+=============+
```

> Table bookings

```
+====+========+============+============+
| ID | car_id | date_from  | date_to    |
+====+========+============+============+
| 1  | 2      | 2018/01/01 | 2018/02/01 |
+----+--------+------------+------------+
| 2  | 1      | 2018/03/01 | 2018/04/01 |
+----+--------+------------+------------+
| 3  | 1      | 2018/05/01 | 2018/06/01 |
+----+--------+------------+------------+
| 4  | 2      | 2018/07/01 | 2018/08/01 |
+====+========+============+============+
```

I need a SQL query which returns all available cars in a specific time period. That means: If I give the query parameters `2018/01/13` and `2018/01/17`, I will only get car number 2 because the other is not available.

Here is my first idea:

```
select c.id, 
       c.mark
from cars c
join bookings b on c.id = b.car_id
where to_date('2017/01/13', 'yyyy/mm/dd') not between b.date_from and b.date_to
  and to_date('2017/01/17', 'yyyy/mm/dd') not between b.date_from and b.date_to;
```

This gives me more rows than I expect.

What should be the right query to achieve this?

**Edit:** I'm on Oracle 12c

Comment: You should exclude the records where the from date is later then your to parameter and those where the to date is earlier then your from parameter.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm on Oracle 12c

Comment: Your query uses dates in 2017, when there were no bookings anyway.

Comment: It looks like car 1 should be available, because it only has bookings for March and May. Car 2 is booked for January and July and so it is not available for your mid-January dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id,
       c.mark
FROM cars c
JOIN bookings b ON c.id = b.car_id
WHERE (to_date('2017/01/13', 'yyyy/mm/dd') < b.date_from AND to_date('2017/01/17', 'yyyy/mm/dd') < b.date_to)
  OR (to_date('2017/01/13', 'yyyy/mm/dd') < b.date_from AND to_date('2017/01/17', 'yyyy/mm/dd') < b.date_to)
```

Comment: This returns some rows twice

Comment: This returns all the rows, because all of the bookings are in 2018. Changing the parameters to 2018 still returns both cars, as it just excludes booking #1.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood the requirement correctly, you are looking for cars that do not have any bookings for the specified date range. Therefore, you should not join to the `bookings` table, because that will only give you cars with existing bookings for other periods. You are looking for cars where no booking exists, so:

```
with cars (id, mark, description) as
       ( select 1, '1234 AB', 'Volvo V70' from dual union all
         select 2, '4567 CD', 'VW Golf' from dual )
   , bookings (id, car_id, date_from, date_to ) as
       ( select 1, 2, date '2018-01-01', date '2018-02-01' from dual union all
         select 2, 1, date '2018-03-01', date '2018-04-01' from dual union all
         select 3, 1, date '2018-05-01', date '2018-06-01' from dual union all
         select 4, 2, date '2018-07-01', date '2018-08-01' from dual )
select c.*
from   cars c
where  not exists
       ( select 1 from bookings b
         where  b.car_id = c.id
         and    (   date '2018-01-13' between b.date_from and b.date_to
                 or date '2018-01-17' between b.date_from and b.date_to )
       );
```

Result:

```
        ID MARK    DESCRIPTION
---------- ------- -----------
         1 1234 AB Volvo V70
```

Car 1 is available, because it only has bookings for March and May, while the Golf is booked for January and July.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
DECLARE @dateToCheck datetime

SELECT cars.id, cars.mark, cars.description FROM cars
INNER JOIN bookings ON bookings.car_id = car.id
WHERE @dateToCheck BETWEEN booking.date_from AND booking.date_to
```

Comment: This should not work, because I'm on a Oracle 12c instance.

Comment: @Markus, then add <oracle> tag to your question.